# How does sharing missions work?

Tags: the-secret-world

The help files aren't very specific about this, but apparently you're supposed to be able to hit the 'share' button in your missions journal to give the quest you're currently on to party members.

However, I was recently trying this with a duo partner, but it didn't actually seem to do anything.  Nothing happened when hitting the button (other than the person hitting it got the 'SHARING MISSION: ' popups).

It didn't matter if we were right next to each other, who was leader, if we had appropriate empty mission slots, if we then took the mission manually but were on different steps....basically this thing didn't seem to do anything.

How do we actually get this working?  Is there a restriction we were missing? What's it actually supposed to do?

Comment: This may be relevant - Patch 1.0.2 [Sharing Side missions should now work even when the character receiving the new mission already has one or two Side missions](http://crygaia.com/update-notes-1-0-2/).

Comment: @pixel I tried this the day before I posted this question, so that patch was already in place.

Comment: understood! to be honest I've not found the 'share quest' system very intuitive at all, I'll be on later if you want to do more testing

Comment: @pixel - Absolutely, we should test this

Answer (score 1):

I've only used it once, and it was a while ago, so perhaps it has broken since then.
I picked up a quest and was able to share it with my party members when they did not also have the quest. My party members were in the same town area, so it didn't seem particularly useful since they could just pick it up themselves with a 10-second walk.

Comment: Look at the timestamp - this question was asked about a month after the game originally launched.  If anything, it's been FIXED since this was posted.